# Characteristic polynomial of a symmetric integer matrix

Tags: matrices, polynomials

I am wondering what, if anything, is known about the characteristic polynomials of integer symmetric matrices.  I believe I read somewhere that not every polynomial with integer coefficients can be a characteristic polynomial for an integer matrix (correct me if I am wrong).  What I would like to be true is that basically there aren't really any constraints in some sense.

Comment: For starters, it cannot have any complex roots.

Comment: Every _monic_ polynomial with integer coefficients is the characteristic polynomial of its companion matrix (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix). 

Comment: Yoav... complex? That's quite a restriction... :P

Comment: Symmetric matrices only!

Comment: He means that the eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix are real.

Comment: Think of a simple case: $2\times 2$ symmetric matrices with trace zero. The question becomes, which integers may be expressed as the sum of two squares? The answer is well-known, and yes there are constraints! 

Comment: It's true, characteristic polynomials of $2\times 2$ symmetric matrices of trace 0 have constraints. For one, the coefficient in front of x then automaticlaly becomes 0 (or whatever else you restrict the trace to be).  So clearly a constraint on the trace puts a constraint on the polynomial.  But I'm not asking for trace 0. If you take ANY intger 2 by 2 symmetric matrix, then there are a lot fewer constraints.  I am wondering what results are known in general, for characteristic polynomials of integer symmetric matrices.  Of course it must have real roots.


Comment: So if I give you a polynomial with integer coefficients and real roots, how do I know if it's a characteristic polynomial for an integer symmetric matrix or not?


Comment: Some information is in the paper E. Bender and N. P. Herzberg, *Linear and Multilinear Algebra* **2** (1974), 173--178.

Comment: For $n=2$ I think it is not possible to get $x^2+bx+c$ where $(b,c)$ is $(0,1)$ or $(2,2)$ mod 4.

Comment: If $x^2+bx+c$ is the characteristic polynomial of a (two by two) symmetric matrix then the discriminant $b^2-4c$ is a sum of two squares. This is valid over any commutative ring. The converse holds when $2$ is invertible, and also if the ring is $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Richard, thank you for the reference: somehow I couldn't find a relevant one through a usual search.  Tom -- I can see that the 2 by 2 case is restrictive (though actually for my purposes the constraint isn't so strong, but that's not really relevant).  My intuition though is that the constraints should be looser the higher the degree of the polynomial, but perhaps this is off.